# Return Null if Formula Referenced Field is Null in Formula Field

Tags: formula, case, custom-field, formula-field

I want to build a custom formula field on the Case object. I have a picklist field called Efforts.
Picklist field values are 1 min, 15 min, 30 min, 1 hour, 2 hours, 4 hours, 1 day, More than 1 day

I am building the formula field like below.

Formula Field(Number) - Return type is number.

```
Formula Field =

CASE(
     TEXT(Effort__c ),
     "5 min", 5,
     "15 min", 15,
     "30 min", 30,
     "1 hour", 60,
     "2 hours", 120,
     "4 hours", 240,
     "More than 1 day", 960,
     "1 day", 480, 
     0
)
```

**The problem is whenever the field Effort__c is null then this formula field is showing the value 0 (as an else condition in the `CASE`). I want this to be null if the picklist is null.**

I've checked **Treat blank fields as blanks**

Any help is appreciable thanks!

Comment: Try replacing 0 by null

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**You just need to pass the default NULL instead of 0**

```
Formula Field =

CASE(
     TEXT(Effort__c ),
     "5 min", 5,
     "15 min", 15,
     "30 min", 30,
     "1 hour", 60,
     "2 hours", 120,
     "4 hours", 240,
     "More than 1 day", 960,
     "1 day", 480, 
     NULL
)
```

Comment: Simple. But learned unknown. Thanks